# Object created, but for some reason throwing an NRE when adding to a list

Tags: c#, winforms, nullreferenceexception

I have declared this list:

```
public ObservableCollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
```

and then tried to create an object and add it to the list here:

```
Order curOrder = new Order(method, category, surchargeYesRadio.Checked, double.Parse(numTxt.Text));
Orders.Add(curOrder);
```

but for some strange reason, on the second line, it's throwing a null reference exception and breaking the program. I looked at  my local variables and it shows it as having set values and everything. A screenshot is below:

[image: Why a NullReferenceException?]

Thanks in advance. I'm really confused.

Comment: Are you sure `Orders` is initialized and not null?

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes these things are so obvious. -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is `Orders` that is null, not `curOrder`.